# Transcoding 1080p h264 to h265 w/ FFmpeg - Unexpectedly Extreme Reduction In Size

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, h.264, h.265

I have a collection of h264 videos from a digital camera that I'm re-encoding to h265 (HEVC).  The FFmpeg options I'm using are:

```
-c:v libx265 -preset medium -x265-params crf=20:keyint=30 -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -map_metadata 0
```

While "quality" is obviously subjective, after quite a bit of reading, it seems like most people agree that CRF of around 23 is a pretty good compromise (default is 28; lower is better).  I dropped down to 20 for even higher quality.  The resulting HEVC videos are visually almost identical to the source - the only way to really perceive a difference is to take a screenshot & zoom in, but for regular viewing, the results are excellent.

However, I'm a bit shocked by the filesizes. My understanding was that HEVC could provide roughly the same video quality as h264 in roughly half the space for 1080p+ footage, but in many cases I'm ending up with videos of only 5% the size.  This comes down to bitrate, of course - where the source videos were ~50Mbps, the compressed ones are anywhere from 30Mbps all the way down to 700kbps.

My question: how can it be possible to be getting such massive space savings? Excellent quality full HD video at 700kbps?  Doesn't that seem like an extremely low bitrate given CRF=20?

Here's an example: [65MB source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qgm2gir3cxaxi7/17-11-10%29%20161113%20Botswana%20-%20Chobe%20NP%20-%20Day%202%20-%20Game%20Drive%20-%20Birds%20C%20%28A7S%29.MP4?dl=0) -> [compressed down to 1.6MB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/afe4y9f3jty17x1/17-11-10)%20161113%20Botswana%20-%20Chobe%20NP%20-%20Day%202%20-%20Game%20Drive%20-%20Birds%20C%20(A7S).FFM.mp4?dl=0). 40 times smaller, & still looks excellent...?

Comment: Also see [ffmpeg output file smaller than input file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61580736/) which is also about digital camera → ffmpeg file size differences.

Answer (score 3):

The savings estimate for HEVC with respect to H.264 is a comparison between two encoding runs which produce output of roughly similar quality, as measured using an established visual quality metric such as PSNR or SSIM. Your 50 Mbps source will have been produced by encoders chasing that target bitrate with a short keyframe interval, not using the full arsenal of encoding tools, such as deep motion search or long GOPs.

But as you mentioned, differences can be spotted upon close visual scrutiny, but that isn't relevant to normal viewing conditions.

Comment: So basically: the huge difference in filesize with reasonably comparable visual results is because the original video wasn't compressed particularly well (the camera is just doing a very simple "dumb" approach), while ffmpeg is doing much more complex analysis? That's what allows it to get such good results in such a tiny fraction of the bitrate?

Comment: The camera designers chose a codec suited to quickly compressing video before storing it, as well as suited to playback on the camera itself (assuming it has that feature).  Space was not the highest priority consideration.  That's a very different use case than playing on a device with a (relatively) powerful CPU and possibly hardware acceleration.